# Tension while hanging from a bar

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image: FBD]

Consider angle = $x^ \circ$. Then according to a free-body diagram
$$mg=2T\text{cos}x$$ and
$$T=\frac {mg}{2\text{cos}x}$$
So I know $x$ is mostly $0^ \circ$. But what about at $180^ \circ$? Is it still minimum? At what angle between your arms would you experience minimum tension while hanging from a bar? Would tension be negative at 180°?

Comment: Please clarify your question with a diagram, for example, to show how you’re defining the angle. It looks like you’ve already shown that the tension goes to infinity, as expected, as perfectly horizontal supports can’t ever counteract a vertical gravitational load. So I’m not sure what you’re asking about.

Comment: Added the diagram

Comment: Try the 180°, you will feel it is not possible!

Comment: Um yes practically no but in theory?

Comment: The diagram doesn’t match the equation of equilibrium. Try going slower, working with the resolved components of one arm at a time. You have a factor-of-two error.

Comment: Do you mean that the angle I'm considering is not with respect to the arms but the vertical?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question and not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: @gandalf61 No. There is nothing conceptual here at all. In fact, there is nothing to answer. The correct equation has already been derived and everything OP is asking can be found by just looking at the equation. As such it is a "do it for me" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. $T = \frac {mg} {2 \cos(x)}$ where $x$ is *half* the angle between the arms. When $x=0$ (arms vertical below the bar) we have $T = \frac {mg} 2$. As $x$ approaches $90$ degrees (arms horizontal) then $T$ approaches infinity. When $x$ is greater than $90$ degrees your shoulders are above the bar and $T$ becomes negative, meaning that the arms are now in compression and not in tension. Finally when $x$ reaches $180$ degrees  (arms vertical but above the bar) then $T = - \frac {mg} 2$.